# Firefox OS - save file in the app directory

Tags: javascript, audio, io, firefox-os, howler.js

I am currently developing an audio editing application for firefox OS ([github](https://github.com/loreV/firebeat)). That uses, for playback, Howler JS ([link](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library)).

On Firefox OS, I can easily play audio files which are within the application folder (does not matter where) only by passing an URL to Howler, but, if I want to create new audio files (recording audio),  I then need to save them somewhere on the internal memory.

The problem is : Howler js does not support playback of blob files (even when I try to get the URL - window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)).

Is there a way to save the files the app creates directly withing the application folder? (So I will be able to reference them using an url?)

If not, what's a good way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Any file that is packaged in the app can be accessed using a relative url. Which means you don't have to get a blob or anything.
2. It won't be possible to save assets (at runtime) in the app folder as far as I can tell. The only way to access the app folder requires you to have the `webapp-manage` permission and that your application has to be certified.
3. It's unlikely that `Howler.js` doesn't work with blob urls as they are not much different from any other url. There might be a bug in FirefoxOS though.

From the documentation, it is said that you should use the "format" property to set the file format of the url if it isn't possible to get it from the url

```
var sound = new Howl({
   urls: [URL.createObjectUrl(blob)],
   format: 'mp3',
   ....
})
```

As a side note, I have to say that for each use of `URL.createObjectUrl(blob)`, you should also call `URL.revokeObjectUrl(url)`. I haven't read much about it but as I understand, the browser will keep the blob in memory as long as the url isn't revoked. Each call to the `createObjectUrl` method will create a new URL that reference to the blob. In order to free the blob, you'll have to free also all urls.

From the documentation, the urls won't be revoked by themselves... Which means that if you loose a reference to a URL you previously created, your web application will leak memory as the blob won't get freed unless the `unload` event is called on the document.

So as you write your application, I'd suggest creating a pool of URLs that you can manage.

```
function UrlPool() {
  this.assets = new Map()
}

UrlPool.prototype.getUrl = function (asset, blob) {
  var url = this.assets.get(asset)
  if (!url) {
    url = URL.createObjectUrl(blob)
    this.assets.set(asset, url)
  }
  return url
}

UrlPool.prototype.removeUrl = function (asset) {
  var url = this.assets.get(asset)
  if (url) {
    URL.revokeObjectUrl(url)
    this.assets.delete(asset)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately passing the link to the Howl object does not work. I tried on chrome and firefox, but the console does not output any error.  Just to be clear, this does not work: `new Howl({
            src: [window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)],
            onend: function() {
                alert('Finished!');
            }
        }
    ).play();`

Comment: Ok I found the solution: it was quite dumb of me. Howler needs to get suggested the file extension in order to understand the stream type. Just add the "ext" property and pass it an array with the extension and it will work correctly.

Comment: Ah yes that make sense. It remind me a comment about a browser available for FirefoxOS. flac files need to have a filename like this: "file.flac.mp3" without this, FirefoxOS doesn't find "flac" files as the extension doesn't seem to be natively supported as "music" media.

Comment: could you be more elaborate about the solution, as i am facing the same issue. What do you mean, add the "ext" property, What do i add it to?

Comment: thank you, I have tried this and it is not working for me, dont know why. Will post my fix if i figure it out. Thanks nonetheless for the prompt response